# Mapbox linked to outside chart to show elevation

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am wondering if it's possible to do something like this with Mapbox GL:

https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-elevation/examples/leaflet-elevation_geojson-data.html

I would like to have interaction between a chart and Mapbox by moving the marker either on the chart or either on the map.
I googled for this but i didn't find anything for Mapbox GL, just for Leaflet.
Currently i'm using Chart.js and Mapbox and i don't see how to manage to reproduce the above example.

Any hints maybe?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm for you that it is possible to build something like this using Mapbox GL JS.